# to align a dropdown on right of menu

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am creating a website, there are two dropdowns in a menu, one is aligned to left and one is aligned to extreme right of menu. I tried to align another dropdown using spaces but sub ul tag is not visible at all. Below is HTML and CSS for reference. Please suggest if any.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#dropbtn").click(function(){
        $("#moreMgmt").toggleClass("show");
    });
    $("#dropbtn2").click(function(){
        $("#moreTech").toggleClass("show");
    });
});
```

```css
   <style>
body{
    font-family:Calibri;
}
.header{
    border:1px solid red;
}
.menu{
    overflow:hidden;
    background-color:#333;
    font-family:Arial;
}
.menu a {
    float: left;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.dropdown {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.dropdown #dropbtn {
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 16px;    
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    background-color:#333;
}
.menu a:hover, .dropdown:hover #dropbtn {
    background-color: limegreen;
}
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}
.dropdown-content a {
    float: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}
.show {
    display: block;
}

#dropbtn2 {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#dropbtn2:hover, #dropbtn2:focus {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}

.dropdown2 {
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    
}

.dropdown-content2 {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    overflow: auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    right: 0;
    left:auto;
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content2 a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown2 a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}
```

```html
    <div class="header">
    <h2>My Website</h2>
</div>

<!-- adding menu-->
<div class = "menu">
    <a href="#">Home</a>
    <a href="#">Home</a>
    <div class="dropdown">
       <button id="dropbtn">More</button>
          <div class="dropdown-content" id="moreMgmt">
            <a href="#">Home</a>
                <a href="#">Home</a>
                <a href="#">Home</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="dropdown2">
          <button id="dropbtn2">More</button>
          <div class="dropdown-content2" id="moreTech">
               <a href="#">Home</a>
               <a href="#">Home</a>
               <a href="#">Home</a>
          </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

I have used Jquery to toggle the ul tags of first dropdown, but its not possible with second one. Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't see 2 dropdowns in your code...

Comment: I have added previously, I have removed for now. You can add your own code.

Comment: First, please don't copy paste whole your code here, anyway post updated. and we see just one drop down menu , where is second ?

Comment: @pedram Sorry I don't understand what do you mean by "OP". And I don't see where I've mentioned something about `select option` "or etc"

Comment: OP = original poster, who asked this question. anyway/ forget that, it was my mistake. @VTodorov

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `float:right` on the dorpdown that you want to position on the right and you may wanna use classes instead of ids when calling dropdown element so you don't repeat the code all over again

**See code snippet**:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".dropdown button").click(function() {
   $(this).next().toggleClass("show");
  });
});
```

```css
font-family:Calibri;

}
.header {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.menu {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  font-family: Arial;
}
.menu a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.dropdown button {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: #333;
}
.menu a:hover,
.dropdown:hover button {
  background-color: limegreen;
}
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}
.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
.show {
  display: block;
}
.dropdown-right {
  float: right;
}
.dropdown-right .dropdown-content{
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header">
  <h2>My Website</h2>
</div>

<!-- adding menu-->
<div class="menu">
  <a href="#">Home</a>
  <a href="#">Home</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button>More</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content" id="moreMgmt">
      <a href="#">Home</a>
      <a href="#">Home</a>
      <a href="#">Home</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown dropdown-right">
    <button>right</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content" id="moreMgmt">
      <a href="#">Home</a>
      <a href="#">Home</a>
      <a href="#">Home</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```